# Compile a c++ file with a different header name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I have a file with a main function (file1.cpp). This main function uses a function that is defined in another file (file2.cpp). There is a header file for file2.cpp, but its name is different. So its not called file2.h but hdr2.h. When I build the project I get an unresolved external symbol error for the function that is used in main. The header file is defined in main but it doesn't seem to be compiling the function that is in file2.cpp. Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: It's surely not because of different naming of the included files :P ...

Comment: Agreed header names need not match the cpp file. The problem is elsewhere and we can not help with only the information you posted.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the header file and the name of the associated implementing source file need not be related. Indeed you can have a header file without any associated implementing source file, or a header file whose implementation spreads over multiple source files.

An unresolved external symbol error simply tells you that the linker cannot find a symbol that you used. That means that you declared a symbol, but did not define it. Since you have source for all the code, this means that you have not passed to to linker the compiled object that provides the definitions. The way you would resolve that is to simply add the defining source files to the project. Once you do that, Visual Studio will compile these source files, and pass the output objects to the linker.

According to your question, the missing symbols are defined in `file2.cpp`. Simply add that file to your Visual Studio project.

---

If you include the file in the project, and the error remains, then it would seem that the unresolved symbol is not in fact defined by that file.

Comment: I do have the source file in the project. I created a folder in the Visual Studio solution explorer and placed it in that. So do I need to do something else?

Comment: No. If the source file is compiled and the output passed to the linker, and the linker cannot find a definition, then there is no definition.

Comment: Putting a file inside the same folder tree as your project does not add the file to the project. You need to add it to the project in the Visual Studio GUI.

Comment: I just added the file to the prj without the folder and its ok now. But I have one more problem ;). There is a variable that is defined as extern in a file. The variable is defined as static in another file. I have both files in the prj but I am betting an unresolved external symbol error.

Comment: I don't about that other problem. Hard to grasp the details in comments. I think I answered the question you asked here.